# ruby Redo method

Tags: ruby

Im learning RUBY but I having issues with the redo method. Im playing around with loops and iterators trying to get the hang of them. I have the following code:

```
def question (quest , ans )
  puts quest
  a = gets.chomp
  if a == ans
    puts "good job"
  else
    puts "Try Again!"
    a = gets.chomp
    redo
  end
end
```

Everything works fine as long as redo is in the method. I want the block to re-run until the user inputs the correct answer. Can some one tell whats is wrong with this block?

Comment: `redo` isn’t a method, it’s a keyword.

Answer (score 4):

`redo`, like `retry` is to be used inside a loop.

You can change your code to

```
def question(quest, ans)
  puts quest

  puts "Try Again!" while gets.chomp != ans

  puts "good job"
end
```

Comment: Thanks for that, thats look much cleaner, but Im still not sure how to use redo then ... Isn't redo inside the block? It is placed before the end for the if loop.

Comment: a `if` block is not a loop. Check this: http://rubyquicktips.com/post/1122838559/redo-vs-retry for info on `redo`.

Answer (score 4):

`redo` is supposed to be used inside a loop and it repeats the current iteration, so in your code if you want to use `redo` put it inside some loop e.g.

```
def question (quest , ans )
  1.times do
    puts quest
    a = gets.chomp
    if a == ans
      puts "good job"
    else
      puts "Try Again!"
      redo
    end
  end
end
```

and this will start working, though it is very counter-intuitive, you are looping one time but you are not :)

better way for such case is to just loop till you get the answer.